# What exactly is this plant resembling Conyza?

Tags: species-identification, botany

This plant grows on my balcony in Vienna, Austria. It gained most of it’s current height (30-35cm) during the last 2 weeks. Before I didn’t notice it. 
[image]
It is covered with tiny white hairs. I conducted a couple of tests. They never stung. 
The leaves are toothed (I believe “serrate” is the official terminus for this type of edge).

From a central leaf vein, more veins spread out in a manner that seems somewhat irregular to my untrained eye:
[image]

Edit: Now, in July, that is about 2 months later, it bears flowers.  Furthermore it is about 3 times taller. I believe there were seed heads, which have been blown and washed away. All of this would fit *Conyza* mentioned in the comments, but the shape and density leaves  appear to differ from C. [boranensis](http://swbiodiversity.org/seinet/collections/individual/index.php?occid=1119448) or C. [canadensis](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanadisches_Berufkraut).
[image]

Edit: now, still July some seed heads have reappeared 
[image]

Comment: It is similar to Conyza canadensis, but the shape of the leaves makes me uncertain

Comment: Conyza canadensis can have these serrated leaves, although usually not this strong. The amount of flowers is also a bit much. Hmm, dunno...